# highchart displaying only ever other point on a line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a series that contains information at 15 minute intervals.  I want the series to only display a point at 30 minute intervals. I have combed through [High charts api](http://api.highcharts.com/). But it doesn't seem to have a way only changing the series display without changing the x-axis. Does anyone know what option i need to include in the highchart decleration to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do it yourself?

```
    var someData = [[0,29.9], [1,71.5],[2, 106.4], [3,129.2], [4,144.0], [5,176.0], [6,135.6],[7, 148.5], [8,216.4], [9,194.1], [10,95.6], [11,54.4]];

    ....

    series: [{
        data: $.grep(someData, function(i,j){
            return j % 2 == 0;
        })
    }]
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uQuLL/).

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

How about:

```
   series: [{
        data: $.map(someData, function(i,j){
            return {
                x: i[0],
                y: i[1],
                marker: {
                    enabled: j % 2 == 0
                }
            };
        })
    }]
```

Another fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uQuLL/2/).

Comment: In your example you are removing elements from the array. I want all elements to exist in the array, but have only the "circle"/"dot" to display every fourth element. So for example in your fiddler february data isnt not taken into account in the slope. What I need is January to have a dot, then february and march data to show in the graph but only april have a dot.